# Concat multiple columns with loop Pyspark

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark

I have n arrays of string columns. I would like concatenate this n columns in one, using a loop.

I have this function to concat columns:

```
def concat(type):
    def concat_(*args):
        return list(chain(*args))
    return udf(concat_, ArrayType(type))

concat_string_arrays = concat(StringType())
```

And in the following example, I have 4 columns that I will concatenate like this:

```
df_aux = df.select('ID_col',concat_string_arrays(col("patron_txt_1"),col("patron_txt_2"),col('patron_txt_3'),col('patron_txt_0')).alias('patron_txt')
```

But, if I have 200 columns, how can I use dynamically this function  with a loop?

Comment: Can you give us a snippet how your data looks like? And how the result should look in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `*` operator to pass a list of columns to your concat UDF:

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("1", "2","3","4"), 
                                 ("5","6","7","8")], 
                                 ('ID_col', 'patron_txt_0','patron_txt_1','patron_txt_2'))  

def concat(type):
    def concat_(*args):
        return list(chain(*args))
    return udf(concat_, ArrayType(type))


concat_string_arrays = concat(StringType())

#Select the columns you want to concatenate 
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith("patron_txt")]

#Use the * operator to pass multiple columns to concat_string_arrays
df.select('ID_col',concat_string_arrays(*cols).alias('patron_txt')).show()
```

This results in the following output:

```
+------+----------+
|ID_col|patron_txt|
+------+----------+
|     1| [2, 3, 4]|
|     5| [6, 7, 8]|
+------+----------+
```